# SDK Manager: Failed to install. SDK android platform 3.0 API 11, revision 2

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

> Failed to rename directory D:\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-11
>   to D:\android-sdk-windows\temp\PlatformPackage.old01. Failed to rename
>   directory D:\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-11 to
>   D:\android-sdk-windows\temp\PlatformPackage.old01. Failed to rename
>   directory D:\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-11 to
>   D:\android-sdk-windows\temp\PlatformPackage.old01. Failed to rename
>   directory D:\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-11 to
>   D:\android-sdk-windows\temp\PlatformPackage.old01. Failed to rename
>   directory D:\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-11 to
>   D:\android-sdk-windows\temp\PlatformPackage.old01.

This is the message that I get when running the AndroidSDK manager when try to update the sdk manager.

SDK Manager: Failed to install
A folder failed to be moved..
it suggests that something else is using the folder..like antivirus..but nothing does!!!

I cant update the SDK manager and add a component called: 
SDK android platform 3.0 API 11, revision 2.

How can i install that component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got that message once because I had an explorer window open to that directory. If it isn't antivirus, then try having the sdk manager as your only open window. If that fails, then open task manager and end every process that could be using it. If that fails, then something is probably wrong with your computer.

Comment: Disabling antivirus did not work for me.  @Core's answer of running Eclipse as administrator worked for me.

Answer (score 15):

On Windows 7, I got the same messages (I tried to do an SDK update by starting AVD manager within Eclipse).  I think the root cause is needing Admin permissions for the SDK folder.  So it might not be affecting folks who didn't allow the SDK to install under "Program Files...".

**My fix was to run "SDK Manager.exe" as administrator**.

Comment: Also, running Eclipse as administrator seems to then run SDK Manager with the correct permissions if you want to start the SDK Manager from within Eclipse.

Answer (score 9):

Here's the problem I ran into and how I fixed it:

1. The program that is using that folder is Eclipse itself.  So using the Android SDK manager and launching it from Eclipse creates an situation where the SDK Manager tries to update a folder that Eclipse is using.  When you shut down Eclipse...you shut down the Android SDK manager.  So you get stuck in an endless and silly situation.

To solve this:

1. Close Eclipse and don't ever update the Android SDK from Eclipse again.
2. Navigate to where your Android SDK is installed, and then launch it from there by double clicking: SDK Manager.exe
3. Once you do this you can now download and install all updates needed without having Eclipse open.

Comment: +1 - This is what solved it for me. I think the root problem was that Eclipse was constantly restarting adb.exe, even after I killed it, and ADB was using that folder.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation, but the process that has locked the folder is the SDK manager itself, not Eclipse.  And yet, it's throwing this error.  Very stupid.  I'm using process explorer and detecting all open file handles, and the only process that opens and locks that location, is confirmed as SDK Manager.  I must somehow update without using the SDK manager.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

This was my exact situation, but closing everything I could didn't do the trick. I finally (d'oh) tried a re-install of the SDKs from the Android Dev site:

[Android SDK - developer.android.com/sdk](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

... and it did the trick for me! It installed right away, started running the manager, and began updating the ones that previously wouldn't update!

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if anyone is still interested in this, but...

When I got this problem, I thought I surely had the solution when I realized that I had open projects which were accessing the Android version I was trying to update. After closing the projects, I got the same error again!?!

What I did to make it work was this:

1.In the command window, **adb kill-server**

2.Eclipse immediately starts trying to reconnect to adb. Note that Eclipse will restart adb shortly.

3.Before that restart occurs, do **adb start-server** in the command window. (Now, I think the process isn't owned by Eclipse and it will stop trying to restart adb.

4.Open the AVT Manager within Eclipse and do the update.

Buggy!

Answer (score 1):

Run Eclipse as Administrator, then start the SDK manager and update.

Answer (score 1):

If none of the above solutions work for you, then this might be the case of Terminal/shell prompts open navigating to Android-sdk folders. Close all those terminal windows and try again.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error from the Eclipse IDE.

1. Close the Android SDK Manager and Eclipse IDE.
2. Run the Android SDK Manager as an Administrator.

You can do this by right clicking on the exe or menu shortcut and then select the `Run As Administrator` option.

Answer (score 0):

Core's answer is the best. Let me expand and say that the trick is to shut-down Exlipse and run `SDK Manager.exe` directly. You'll find it at the top level of your `android-sdk-windows` folder or wherever your android SDK lives. It seems that the rouge process that is not allowing the old SDK folder to be moved doesn't belong to a virus scanner but rather is one of Eclipse's own processes!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. my eclipse is closed, and I use lock explorer to see that the lock is actually held by the sdk manager itself. it seems the Android SDK manager is trying to update itself with Android SDK tools rev.19  This is fairly typical of google software.

Answer (score 0):

I found that "Java.exe" is file that lock the SDK/Tools folder.by kill java.exe by process manager SDK manager automatically close.SDK manager neet to java.exe for execute but java.exe lock folder that SDK manager want to renamer it!!!