# Eclipse is loading framework information and the layout library from the SDK folder.

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

im having trouble with xml graphical view.xml is not showing how the code will look like and shows this kind of error. `Eclipse is loading framework information and the layout library from the SDK folder.activity_main.xml will refresh automatically once the process is finished.` ive work on several approach like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022977/sdk-manager-failed-to-install-sdk-android-platform-3-0-api-11-revision-2) and [this](http://www.codeonastick.com/2013/04/how-to-fix-android-fix-eclipse-is.html) and [this](http://www.brianklug.com/w/page/15052155/How%202%20fix%20error:%20Eclipse%20is%20loading%20framework%20information%20and%20the%20Layout%20library%20from%20the%20SDK%20folder) and [enter link description here](http://androidbook.blogspot.com/2009/07/when-eclipse-loading-framework.html) but unfortunately nothing happened any other way for this to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This solved my issue. Basically reinstall SDK manager. 
http://www.codeonastick.com/2013/04/how-to-fix-android-fix-eclipse-is.html

Comment: Great link.. solved my issue.
Delete latest SDK and then reinstall it.

Comment: The link is dead. Can you post a description?

Answer (score 2):

I use Android 5.0.1 and deleting the sdk and reinstalling it solved my problem too...